# Blockchain.info wallet json created device name

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I have a blockchain info wallet. From this I got a json file. Looking at the unencrypted file there are all my addresses and private keys. However there is one strange address with the following parameters:

```
"created_time": 0,
"created_device_name": "external",
"created_device_version": "0"
```

what does this mean?
Also the address has lots of transactions on it even though I never used it.

(All other addresses are of type:

```
"created_device_name": "javascript_web"
```

)

Anyone know what this is?

Comment: Is it just the address or is there a private key associated with that address as well? We frequently see people asking about being defrauded by means of watch-only wallets where they are actually unable to spend funds but just watch some other users address thinking it's theirs.